# Add one separated class from package to CLASSPATH

Tags: java

I have a directory with java classes:

```
[C:]
  java_project
    com
      other_classes
        OtherClass1.java
        OtherClass2.java
      my_class
        MyClass.class
```

MyClass.class has structure:

```
package com.my_class

public class MyClass {
...
```

I want to add to classpath only one class - MyClass.class, and I don't want to add another classes from the whole package to it. I know, that it possible to specify only jars or folders for classpath, so I tried this

```
 java -cp C:\java_project\com\my_class ...
```

But MyClass.class wasn't added to classpath with this command. Can somebody help me to understend is it possible to specify the only one class from separated directory for the classpath?

Comment: what do you mean by *I know, that it possible to specify only jars or folders for classpath* ??

Comment: When you are adding folders to the classpath, you have to specify the root folder containing the package.  So you can only specify C:\java_project. You wouldn't be able to narrowly target MyClass.class without including the other classes as it is setup.  You would have to isolate com\my_class\MyClass.class in its own folder and then add that folder to the classpath.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What is the problem when you use `C:\java_project` in the CLASSPATH setting? Why are there classes `OtherClass1` and `OtherClass2` in that directory structure when they shouldn't be used?

Comment: @Ravi, I mean, that it's allowable only specifying jars or folders(packages) as classpath options. If I'll try to set class to this option it will not work

Comment: @Progman, I'm trying to do this in test purposes. I want to add some class with Spring configuration to my app classes to test them in some case. I have a package with many Spring configuration classes, so adding other of them may affect test